# HTML Text over image

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put 4 headers over an image, but with the code I give something weird happens: The 2 headers on the left get thrown out of the div.

Picture for refrence:[image]

As you can see the div has a red border but the text jumps out of it for some reason.

The code:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: Head;
    src: url('HeadFont.ttf');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: SpecifyLight;
    src: url('SpecifyLight.ttf');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: SpecifyMedium;
    src: url('SpecifyMedium.ttf');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: Android;
    src: url('Android.ttf');
}

BODY {
    background-image: url("bg.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    width: 75%;
    margin:auto;
}

/*Navigatie bar styling*/
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: black;
}

.ulMain {
    background-image: url("menu.png");
    background-position: center;
    background-position: top;
    background-size: 100% auto;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 20px 20px;
}

li {
    float: left;
    border-right: 1px solid #bbb;
}

    li a {
        display: block;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

        li a:hover:not(.active) {
            color: #B8371A;
            background-color: white;
        }

    li:last-child {
        border-right: none;
    }

.active {
    background-color: darkred;
}

h1 {
    width: 100%;
    font-family: Head;
    font-size: 80px;
    margin-top: 0;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    padding: 0;
}

h2 {
    width:100%;
    font-family: Head;
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
}

h3 {
    width:100%;
    font-family: Head;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 0;
}

h4 {
    width:100%;
    font-family: Head;
    font-size: 40px;
    margin: 10px;
    text-align: left;
    color: red;
}

h5 {
    width:100%;
    font-family: Head;
    font-size: 40px;
    text-align: right;
    color: red;
}

header {
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    height: auto;

}

.menu {
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    height: auto;
}

footer {
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #B8371A;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 20px 20px;
}

.content {
    font-family:SpecifyLight;
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}

.bioFoto {
    float: right;
    width: 20%;
    height: auto;
    margin-right: 100px;
    border: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

.website {
    width: 100%;
    margin:auto;
    background-color: lightgray;
}

.headerFoto {
    display:block;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    height: auto;
}

.mainFoto {
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    height: auto;
}

.homePage {
    width:inherit;
    margin:auto;
    border:solid;
    border-color:red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Atlas</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="siteStyle.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="Logo.png" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="website" style="background-color:black">
        <div class="menu">
            <ul>
                <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="bio.html">Biografie</a></li>
                <li><a href="projecten.html">Projecten</a></li>
                <li><a href="galerij.html">Galerij</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <h2 style="color:white">Klik op de opties hier beneden</h2>
            <div class="homePage">
                <img src="grootLogo.png" class="mainFoto">
                <h4 style="position: absolute; top:50%;">Biografie</h4>
                <h5 style="position: absolute; top:50%;">Projecten</h5>
                <h4 style="position: absolute; top:75%;">Galerij</h4>
                <h5 style="position: absolute; top:75%;">Contact</h5>
                <br />
            </div>
    </div>
    <footer></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you minimalise the code as much as possible to produce the effect it is you are having.

Comment: Add `position: relative;` to `.homePage`, it'll position the child elements relatively to it. It would be helpful if you could make your code snippet reflect your image as your current code makes the issue unclear.

Comment: I think that if you get rid of the inline styles 'position: absolute', and organize your h tags above your img tag, you'll begin to see an improvement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short answer

Set `position: relative` to `homePage`.

### Less short answer

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Absolute_positioning):

> The absolutely positioned element is positioned relative to nearest positioned ancestor (non-static). If a positioned ancestor doesn't exist, the initial container is used.

In your case, since all elements are `position: static` (this is the default behavior), this means your 4 absolute elements are relative to the `<html>` tag (e.g. your *initial container*).
Setting `position: relative` (or any value not `static`) on their parent fixes their positioning by making any `top|right|bottom|left` relative to it.

Comment: Oke that worked but they are not in the same line yet. How would i do that?

Comment: This is a different question hehe
What you could do is use the same `h4|h5` tag, and also set the `left|right` to position them. What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: I would want the text to be like the corners of a rectacle around the centeral circle. But should i open a new question to ask that?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand but try `left: 0; top: 0;`, `right: 0; top: 0;`, `left:0; bottom: 0;`, `right:0; bottom: 0;`. _(edited after edit)_

Comment: Is that posible if you use position relative?

Comment: Yes it is, but `position: relative` will move the items from their original position, leaving a blank area. You could also try to use `flexbox` to center things properly, but I'll let you investigate on this matter ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: Head;
    src: url('HeadFont.ttf');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: SpecifyLight;
    src: url('SpecifyLight.ttf');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: SpecifyMedium;
    src: url('SpecifyMedium.ttf');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: Android;
    src: url('Android.ttf');
}

BODY {
    background-image: url("bg.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    width: 75%;
    margin:auto;
}

/*Navigatie bar styling*/
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: black;
}

.ulMain {
    background-image: url("menu.png");
    background-position: center;
    background-position: top;
    background-size: 100% auto;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 20px 20px;
}

li {
    float: left;
    border-right: 1px solid #bbb;
}

    li a {
        display: block;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

        li a:hover:not(.active) {
            color: #B8371A;
            background-color: white;
        }

    li:last-child {
        border-right: none;
    }

.active {
    background-color: darkred;
}

h1 {
    width: 100%;
    font-family: Head;
    font-size: 80px;
    margin-top: 0;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    padding: 0;
}

h2 {
    width:100%;
    font-family: Head;
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
}

h3 {
    width:100%;
    font-family: Head;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 0;
}

h4 {
    width:100%;
    font-family: Head;
    font-size: 40px;
    margin: 10px;
    text-align: left;
    color: red;
}

h5 {
    width:100%;
    font-family: Head;
    font-size: 40px;
    text-align: right;
    color: red;
}

header {
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    height: auto;

}

.menu {
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    height: auto;
}

footer {
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #B8371A;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 20px 20px;
}

.content {
    font-family:SpecifyLight;
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}

.bioFoto {
    float: right;
    width: 20%;
    height: auto;
    margin-right: 100px;
    border: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

.website {
    width: 100%;
    margin:auto;
    background-color: lightgray;
}

.headerFoto {
    display:block;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    height: auto;
}

.mainFoto {
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    height: auto;
}

.homePage {
  position:relative;
    width:inherit;
    margin:auto;
    border:solid;
    border-color:red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Atlas</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="siteStyle.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="Logo.png" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="website" style="background-color:black">
        <div class="menu">
            <ul>
                <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="bio.html">Biografie</a></li>
                <li><a href="projecten.html">Projecten</a></li>
                <li><a href="galerij.html">Galerij</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <h2 style="color:white">Klik op de opties hier beneden</h2>
            <div class="homePage">
                <img src="grootLogo.png" class="mainFoto">
                <h4 style="position: absolute; top:50%;">Biografie</h4>
                <h5 style="position: absolute; top:50%;">Projecten</h5>
                <h4 style="position: absolute; top:75%;">Galerij</h4>
                <h5 style="position: absolute; top:75%;">Contact</h5>
                <br />
            </div>
    </div>
    <footer></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: Head;
    src: url('HeadFont.ttf');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: SpecifyLight;
    src: url('SpecifyLight.ttf');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: SpecifyMedium;
    src: url('SpecifyMedium.ttf');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: Android;
    src: url('Android.ttf');
}

BODY {
    background-image: url("bg.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    width: 75%;
    margin:auto;
}

/*Navigatie bar styling*/
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: black;
}

.ulMain {
    background-image: url("menu.png");
    background-position: center;
    background-position: top;
    background-size: 100% auto;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 20px 20px;
}

li {
    float: left;
    border-right: 1px solid #bbb;
}

    li a {
        display: block;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

        li a:hover:not(.active) {
            color: #B8371A;
            background-color: white;
        }

    li:last-child {
        border-right: none;
    }

.active {
    background-color: darkred;
}

h1 {
    width: 100%;
    font-family: Head;
    font-size: 80px;
    margin-top: 0;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    padding: 0;
}

h2 {
    width:100%;
    font-family: Head;
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
}

h3 {
    width:100%;
    font-family: Head;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 0;
}

h4 {
    width:100%;
    font-family: Head;
    font-size: 40px;
 margin: 10px;
    text-align: left;
    color: red;
}

h5 {
    width:100%;
    font-family: Head;
    font-size: 40px;
    text-align: center; 
 
    color: red;
}

header {
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    height: auto;

}

.menu {
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    height: auto;
}

footer {
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #B8371A;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 20px 20px;
}

.content {
    font-family:SpecifyLight;
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}

.bioFoto {
    float: right;
    width: 20%;
    height: auto;
    margin-right: 100px;
    border: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

.website {
    width: 100%;
    margin:auto;
    background-color: lightgray;
}

.headerFoto {
    display:block;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    height: auto;
}

.mainFoto {
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    height: auto;
}

.homePage {
    width:inherit;
    margin:auto;
    border:solid;
    border-color:red;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="website" style="background-color:black">
        <div class="menu">
            <ul>
                <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="bio.html">Biografie</a></li>
                <li><a href="projecten.html">Projecten</a></li>
                <li><a href="galerij.html">Galerij</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <h2 style="color:white">Klik op de opties hier beneden</h2>
            <div class="homePage">
                <img src="grootLogo.png" class="mainFoto">
                <h4 style="position: absolute; top:33%;">Biografie</h4>
                <h5 style="position: absolute; top:24%;">Projecten</h5>
                <h4 style="position: absolute; top:55%;">Galerij</h4>
                <h5 style="position: absolute; top:46%;">Contact</h5>
                <br />
            </div>
    </div>
    <footer></footer>
</body>
```